# K Prototype initialization kept repeating initializing centroids and initializing clusters step

Tags: python, arrays, cluster-analysis, prototype

I am working on implementing k-Prototype clustering in Python. The data frame shape is (1870995, 28). I have set kproto = KPrototypes(n_clusters=3, verbose=2,max_iter=20). However, the initialization keeps repeating "initializing centroids" and "initializing clusters" and doesn't start iteration steps.

1. Is my data frame is too big ?
2. Should this be expected and I should wait for it to run ?

Here is the printed output :

```
Initialization method and algorithm are deterministic. Setting n_init to 1.
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
Init: initializing centroids
Init: initializing clusters
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have is calling the proto method, you should also call the fit_predict method on it, something like below:

```
kproto = KPrototypes(n_clusters=3, verbose=2, max_iter=20).

kproto.fit_predict(df, categorical=[3, 4, 5]) # categorical column indices
```